# Transforming Second Order to First Order IVP's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I've been given the following IVP:

> $$\begin{cases}x''(t)=\cos(t)\\ x(0)=0 \\ x'(0)=1\end{cases}$$

and am tasked with transforming this to a first order IVP of the form $z(t)=(z_1(t),z_2(t))$ and then solving solving the IVP deduced.

Here's what I've done so far however I am very stuck with where to go from here.

It's clear that as $x''(t)=\cos(t)$ and $x'(0)=1$,
$$x'(t)=\sin(t)+1$$
and from here as $x(0)=0$,
$$x(t)=-\cos(t)+t+1.$$

Hence $x(t)=-x''(t)+t+1$. Where do I go from here? I'd much rather be given a method so I can understand these questions better rather than an answer but I'll take any help I can get at the moment. Thank you.

Comment: The question was too simple, you just computed the full solution. Take the modified problem $\ddot x= \cos(x)$ and apply the task to it. Then apply the same transformation to the original task.

Comment: It seems to me that the goal is to convert a second-order ODE to a system of first-order ODEs. Try letting $y(t)=x'(t)$.

Comment: $(\dot{y},\dot{x})=(\cos t, y)$